# How can I load an npm module or JS file in a Service Worker?

Tags: service-worker, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am building a Chrome extension using Manifest Version 3, which uses Service Workers as the replacement for background pages. I spent a few days earlier this month trying to understand why `import` wasn't working, till it turns out that [service workers don't support `import` yet](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/1585). Obviously I can't add a `<script>` tag either - service workers don't have a DOM to insert a tag into.

**What's the best way to load third party code (like an NPM module or a `.js` file) inside a service worker?**

Comment: If you use webpack it'll handle everything for you and import statement will just work.

Comment: @wOxxOm yep it does. You can mark as a dupe if you like. The confusion was because `import()` (a function I haven't heard of before) and ES6 `imports` are different things.

Comment: @wOxxOm it's cool I've done it, thanks for spotting it - I've edited the title on the other post so it reflects the contents better too.

Comment: hello @mikemaccana, did you able to import the npm package from the service worker? I am facing this issue right now.

Comment: @Nithur yes. See the other answer. I use `rollup` to make bundle of the service worker, and the bundle includes all the imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension service workers aren't exactly the same as web service workers. You can do this, but you need to add the `"type"` key to your `manifest.js`.

```js
"background": {
  "service_worker": "background.js",
  "type": "module"
}
```

There's more information in [the extensions documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/service_workers/#manifest).